# Prestashop overriding default behavior

Tags: prestashop

I'm not a big expert with PrestaShop but this is what I would like to achieve: Everytime a customer confirms an order for a particular product, I would like to send an http request to another server to start the production of the product.

This is what I have in mind: 
Create a file in /override/controlers/front/OrderConfirmationController.php

```
class OrderConfirmationController extends OrderConfirmationControllerCore
{

    public function initContent()
    {

        parent::initContent();

        $url = 'http://server.com/path';
        $data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');

        // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data),
            ),
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

      }
}
```

The issue is that I need certain specifications from the products (size, color, ...) but not all types of products will be sent to that production center.

I am using version 1.6.1.1

Thanks for your help!

Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look into *init()* method of controller that you override 
/controllers/front/OrderConfirmationController.php
there you may see:

```
$order = new Order((int)($this->id_order));
```

in child controller you have access to Order object, so:

```
$products = $order->getProducts();
```

will to get you products list.